# NOTEPAD++ , REPLACE domain\username in to dummydomain007\xxxxxxx

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am having number of lines in the notepad. I want to find the word pattern matching on the lines and need to remove that word ONLY with some other dummy text.

Example
Input line:

```
07-12-2020 User Logged in Started. User Info is 'domain\ID12354' Authentication successful.
07-12-2020 User Logged in Started. User Info is 'domain\ID123adad' Logged in.
07-12-2020 User Logged in Started. User Info is 'domain\ID1xzza' Logged out.
```

Output line

```
07-12-2020 User Logged in Started. User Info is 'dummydomain\xxxxxx' Authentication successful.
07-12-2020 User Logged in Started. User Info is 'dummydomain\xxxxxx' Logged in.
07-12-2020 User Logged in Started. User Info is 'dummydomain\xxxxxx' Logged out.
```

Are we having option to do that in NOTEPAD++ in find and replace option using REGULAR Expression?

OR else, we can use other C# app to mathch RegEx, In that what would be the correct RegEx for this pattern?

Comment: I see that the substring which needed to be replaced is always wrapped with quote chars. This is good marker.

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `'.+?'`
- Replace with: `'dummydomain\\xxxxxx'`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
'           # single quote
.+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
'           # single quote
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: \ should be escaped since its not appearing in the replaced text

Comment: @user1245068: Good catch, thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand from your example, but below is an example that you may adapt
to your needs.

Find what : `'(.+)\\.+'`
Replace with : `'dummydomain\\xxxxxx'`
Search mode : Regular expression

[image: ![enter image description here]